# Opening keyboard on tap in ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ace-editor, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic framework to make a hybrid app. Also I have included the Ace editor. I'm trying to open the keyboard when the user taps on the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this problem is caused by the Ace editor itself. Ace have difficulties with iOS (https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/37)